# How do I create a "hole" in my Qt window?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I would like to create a "hole" in my QMainWindow.

Suppose the black rectangle is the "hole" of a QMainWindow. Inside the rectangle should be anything behind the QMainWindow. For example, if the QMainWindow is opened on top of my desktop, then inside the rectangle should be part of my desktop background image.

Is there any solution to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: What should happen if, for example, a mouse button is pressed in the 'hole'?  Should your application receive the event or should it go to whichever application window is visible through the hole?

Comment: The application should not receive the event. Any window behind the "hole" should handle the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `QWidget::setMask` or `QWindow::setMask`. There is a Qt Example for that: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-shapedclock-example.html

Comment: Thanks. Another question is, since the example says "setting certain window flags will cause the window decoration (title bar, window frame, buttons) to be disabled". So if I use QWidget::setMask and also want a title bar, I should implement one myself?

Comment: @Arsenal591, you dont have to set frameless hint. You need to apply mask only. There is no need in your case to make whole widnow frameless

Comment: But even if frameless hint is not set, the window is still frameless. It looks like setMask() will always cause the window to be frameless

Comment: @Arsenal591 got it. Then, yes. You will have to implement it for yourself. Dragging is easy implemented, closing, maximizing, minimizing -- also, due to corresponding slots presence.